# How to see answers given in a duplicated question

Tags: support, questions, duplicate-questions

My question was marked as duplicated yet it has an answer and the answer was accepted. The linked question have the way worst solution and it does not cover with my question in 100%. Is it possible to see answers given in a question marked as duplicated?

Link: [Inverted transparent triangle with SVG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33802419/inverted-transparent-triangle-with-svg)

Comment: I don't see an answer on your question

Comment: I add link to question

Comment: Maybe it was deleted because I don't see any answer there.

Comment: Well answers was given, but when question was marked as duplicated all answers gone .

Comment: Oh so you want to see the answer that was deleted from your question. Maybe someone will provide a screenshot.

Comment: Yes, that exactly what i want, there was one perfect answer and very complex someone work hard on it - and now when its marked as duplicated its all gone - and answers given in linked post are not really accurate to this problem.

Comment: Odd, a question being marked as a dupe is no reason for answers to be deleted as far as I know.

Comment: @Gimby - Right. I don't know why the owners decided to delete their answer.

Comment: We could just ping the writer @web-tiki

Comment: @Paulie_D Why don't you post a link to a screenshot? And pings don't work on users not present on the post.

Comment: Because then the answer wouldn't be on SO...it would be on Meta and an image. Plus, if the writer wants it visible to non-10k users they have that option. It's not for me to override their wishes.

Comment: @Ganga: Both the approaches that were mentioned in web-tiki's answer are there in the primary thread (the skew approach is in jbutler's answer and SVG is in maioman's answer), so technically they are there. I think this is one reason why he had removed his answer. There was also a meta thread earlier about people answering and then hammering questions (preventing others from answering) which may have influenced the decision. Knowing web-tiki through chat, I am certain that he is not a rep-hunter and so will ask him if he would like to undelete it.

Comment: @Ganga It's been undeleted.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Although deleting answers on duplicates isn't mandatory, answering and using the duplicate closing priviledge can be considered as rep-whoring especialy as the approaches I describe in my answer are already provided in the primary question.

This said, I have undeleted my answer as it specificaly adresses your issue.

Comment: I ended up flagging the questions to request it to be merged with the duplicate. Maybe this way your answer, which seems to be well-received, can show up in the context of the original Q.

Comment: @Ike I don't know if that would be a very good idea as both the approaches in my answer ar already described in the primary

Comment: Perhaps making your answer a community wiki is an acceptable alternative to just deleting it? You can't be wrongfully accused of rep-whoring if you don't get rep.

Comment: Matter of opinion, no? Answers typically often only vary slightly anyway unless the question allows a great deal of variations. It becomes about expression, conciseness, detail, etc. I see it as a shame to see something well-received lost in a shuffle.

Comment: @Gimby Do you know how merges work? I've rarely seen a merge happen. Does the new question get merged with the old one to make it like a super-question? I'm a little worried that otherwise the merged answer might seem to miss the old question a bit, since subtle variations in a question might lead to considerably diverging branches of answers. I've never seen a merge happen -- I just got suggested today that if I see a nice answer to a dupe Q, to request a mod to merge it.

Comment: @Ike the merge target receives all the answers and comments from the source. The source question remains as a "stub" with a link to the target.

Comment: @Ike the questions have been merged.

Comment: @Ike Thank you for your help and answer :) And thank you all guys for support.